# SwiftUI order different structs within view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 2 different structures with many different variables, but each struct has a date variable. I want to present both arrays in a list in SwiftUI in order based on date. How can I combine two arrays of different structs into one then order them based on date?

```swift
struct Struct1: Identifiable, DateSortable {
    let id = UUID()
    let date: Date
    let property1: String // Add other properties specific to Struct1
}

struct Struct2: Identifiable, DateSortable {
    let id = UUID()
    let date: Date
    let property2: Int // Add other properties specific to Struct2
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let structArray: [Struct2] = [
        Struct2(date: Date(), property2: 10), // Example data
        Struct2(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), property2: 20), // Example data
        Struct2(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(172800), property2: 30) // Example data
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(structArray) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("ID: \(item.id)")
                        Text("Date: \(item.date)")
                        Text("Property2: \(item.property2)")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about converting struct1, struct2 into a single data type and then passing it, for i.e, as a generic type into ContentView?

Comment: @son because these specific data types are parameters of views. That would mean I would have to convert them to a single type then reconvert them back so I can pass them as arguments. I feel like there's probably an easier way.

Comment: This might be a case where reference types (ie inheritance) are your friends. Without knowing anything about the size of your datasets, I'm wondering whether you could make your structs classes, inheriting from a DateSortable class? It is then easy to maintain any number of sorted lists of references.

Comment: More I think about it, the better classes sound. Since you need to sort things, depending on exactly how you write it you may end up moving a lot of data around.

Comment: Just use a computed property to combine them however you like and pass it into ForEach's init

Comment: @malhal I really like your suggestion. See my (superfluous) answer below, showing my interpretation.

Comment: Thanks, your way is fine for static data, mine is for dynamic state 

Comment: @malhal How would I modify Ron’s answer to account for a dynamic state. I also do not have static data.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Just make a computed var sortedMyData and put his myData.sorted() in it 

Comment: I edited my last version to make it dynamic, as @malhal suggests. At least I think this is the direction he is suggesting. Surprise, surprise (to me at least) it's a lot less code, and easier to understand. Hope this generalizes to your use case.

Comment: No by dynamic I meant where the arrays are @State, i.e. can dynamically change. You can just change your func to a var (no need to pass in anything), make the 2 arrays be state, and that should be it.

Comment: I assumed he was juggling a larger collection of diverse objects. Having said that, your comments have helped me think about a very similar problem in my own project in much clearer terms. (It's a reference document-based app with multiple datasets, and needs @Observable and all that good binding stuff.) So thanks again.

Comment: @malhal I tried doing what you said and faced another issue, maybe you can look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78236744/swift-ui-large-computed-property-causes-buggy-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much less code than in another answer :)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let myData: [MyWrapper] = [
        MyWrapper(date: Date(), data: Struct1(property1: "hello")),
        MyWrapper(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), data: Struct2(property2: 10)),
        MyWrapper(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(172800), data: Struct2(property2: 30))
    ]
    // !!!ORDER!!!
    .sorted( by: { $0.date < $1.date } )
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(myData) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("ID: \(item.id)")
                        Text("Date: \(item.date)")
                        
                        if let tmp = item.data as? Struct1 {
                            Text("Property1: \(tmp.property1)")
                        }
                        
                        if let tmp = item.data as? Struct2 {
                            Text("Property2: \(tmp.property2)")
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct MyWrapper: Identifiable  {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: Date
    var data: any MyData
}

protocol MyData { }

struct Struct1: MyData {
    let property1: String
}

struct Struct2: MyData {
    let property2: Int
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the far Swiftier solution I couldn't come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my quick start for a reference type implementation. With any luck, one of the real experts will contribute a Swifty solution using value objects.

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            DemoView()
        }
    }
}

struct DemoView: View {
    private var myStuff = Combo()   // The data model containing a sorted list of Struct1 & Struct2s
    @State private var selection = DateSortable(.unknown, date: Date()) // defaults to avoid optionals
/// Decode which kind of object we want to show.
    private func showSubClass(_ item: DateSortable) -> String {
        switch item.whatIAm {
        case .struct1:
            "I'm a 1, with property: \((item as! Struct1).property1)"
        case .struct2:
            "I'm a 2, with property: \((item as! Struct2).property2)"
        case .unknown:
            "Something went wrong"
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Date Sorted Objects")
            List(myStuff.combo, id: \.self) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("ID: \(item.id.uuidString.suffix(4))")
                    Text("Date: \(item.date)")
                    Text(showSubClass(item))
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selection) { print("ID: \(selection.id.uuidString.suffix(4))") } // Show that selection works.
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
/// An enum to tell the subclasses apart.
enum WhatIAm: String {
    case struct1
    case struct2
    case unknown
}
/// Base class defines common elements.
/// I added the enum to distinguish them at runtime. You probably have your own way to do this.
class DateSortable {
    var id: UUID
    var date: Date
    var whatIAm: WhatIAm
    
    init(_ whatIAm: WhatIAm, date: Date) {
        id = UUID()
        self.date = date
        self.whatIAm = whatIAm
    }
}
/// Extension provides required protocol conformance
extension DateSortable: Identifiable, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: DateSortable, rhs: DateSortable) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

class Struct1: DateSortable {
    let property1: String // Add other properties specific to Struct1
    init (date: Date, property1: String) {
        self.property1 = property1
        super.init(.struct1, date: date)
    }
}
class Struct2: DateSortable {
    let property2: Int // Add other properties specific to Struct1
    init ( date: Date, property2: Int) {
        self.property2 = property2
        super.init(.struct2, date: date)
    }
}
/// Expose an array of DateSortable objects
/// The array contains a sorted list of subclass instances
///
class Combo {
    let array1: [Struct1] = [
        Struct1(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(100), property1: "First"), // Example data
        Struct1(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400 * 3), property1: "Second"),
        Struct1(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(172800 * 2), property1: "Third")
    ]
    let array2: [Struct2] = [
        Struct2(date: Date(), property2: 10), // Example data
        Struct2(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), property2: 20), // Example data
        Struct2(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(172800), property2: 30) // Example data
    ]
    var combo: [DateSortable]

    init() {
        var a: [DateSortable] = array1
        a.append(contentsOf: array2)
        combo = a.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date})
    }
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edited to be dynamic. I think this is close to the direction @malhal is thinking. The example bakes the test data into the view, but live data can obviously be passed in.

An implementation using the suggestion from @malhal because I've learned a lot playing with this question. It turns out to relate to part of a project I'm in the middle of refactoring. So thanks to the great contributors.

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            DemoView()
        }
    }
}
struct DemoView: View {
    let array1: [Struct1] = [
        Struct1(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(100), property1: "First"), // Example data
        Struct1(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400 * 3), property1: "Second"),
        Struct1(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(172800 * 2), property1: "Third")
    ]
    let array2: [Struct2] = [
        Struct2(date: Date(), property2: 10), // Example data
        Struct2(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), property2: 20), // Example data
        Struct2(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(172800), property2: 30) // Example data
    ]
    
    func combo(_ items: [any ModelItem]...) -> [any ModelItem] {
        var a = [any ModelItem]()
        for item in items {
            a.append(contentsOf: item)
        }
        return a.sorted(by: { $0.sortKey < $1.sortKey })
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(combo(array1, array2), id: \.id) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("ID: \(item.id)")
                    Text("Date: \(item.date)")
                    Text("Property: \(item.property)")
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 450)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Using Computed Properties")
    }
}

protocol ModelItem {
    var id: UUID {get}
    var date: Date {get}
    var sortKey: Date {get}
    var property: String {get}
}

struct Struct1: ModelItem {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: Date
    let property1: String // Add other properties specific to Struct1
    var sortKey: Date { date }
    var property: String { property1 }
}
struct Struct2: ModelItem {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: Date
    let property2: Int // Add other properties specific to Struc21
    var sortKey: Date { date }
    var property: String { String(property2) }
}
```

[image]