# Swift UI large computed property causes buggy view

Tags: swift, swiftui

This question builds off:
[SwiftUI order different structs within view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78203509/swiftui-order-different-structs-within-view)

The answers in the previous question showed how to put multiple different structs into one array then display it in a Swift UI scroll view. The answers were for static data and the comments pointed out to use a computed property for dynamic data. In my case I have 2 classes (environmentObjects) that are passed at the top of the view hierarchy and each class holds an array of different struct. In the computed property I access these arrays to combine them into the **MyWrapper** array.

My problem is that when the computed property is large and has many elements (around 50) then the view/navigation becomes buggy. When there are only a couple elements in this **MyWrapper** array then the view behaves normally. The arrays must stay in both environmentObject classes. How can I modify my approach to account for larger datasets?

Specifically I am making a messaging app and messages are always outgoing and incoming so the computed property needs to keep updating to order the chats correctly.

```
class ViewModelOne: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var chats = [Struct1]()  //has to stay published
}

class ViewModelTwo: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var chats = [Struct2]()  //has to stay published
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel1: ViewModelOne
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel2: ViewModelTwo
    var combined: [MyWrapper] {
        let arr1 = viewModel1.chats
        let arr2 = viewModel2.chats
        var newWrapper: [MyWrapper] = []
        
        arr1.forEach { element in
            newWrapper.append(MyWrapper(id: UUID(), date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), data: Struct1(property1: "hello")))
        }
        arr2.forEach { element in
            newWrapper.append(MyWrapper(id: UUID(), date: Date().addingTimeInterval(172800), data: Struct2(property2: 30)))
        }
        
        return newWrapper.sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(combined) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("ID: \(item.id)")
                        Text("Date: \(item.date)")
                        
                        if let tmp = item.data as? Struct1 {
                            Text("Property1: \(tmp.property1)")
                        }
                        
                        if let tmp = item.data as? Struct2 {
                            Text("Property2: \(tmp.property2)")
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct MyWrapper: Identifiable  {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: Date
    var data: any MyData
}

protocol MyData { }

struct Struct1: MyData {
    let property1: String
}

struct Struct2: MyData {
    let property2: Int
}
```

Comment: 50 is not a large list, maybe there are other things going on.
 You could try using `LazyVStack` just after your `ScrollView`.

Comment: By resetting the id property on each chat message on every redraw loop you are forcing the entire list to redraw. Is there a way of persistently uniquely identifying each chat message/MyWrapper instance. SwiftUI relies a lot on diffing to deal with changes performantly.

Comment: Usually objects are the cause of performance issues try removing one object and put both arrays in one object and it might be 2x speed

Comment: @WarrenBurton thanks for the tip, I used persistent id's and it did speed up the view. Although there is a little bit of lag left, not as much as before though.

Comment: @malhal in my case I can't put both structs into one object. My situation has multiple classes and structs, not just two, and it would be too much refactoring.

Comment: You should rethink your setup to a more stable approach. Maybe use storage and/or inheritance. Depending on computed properties that redraw every time the body reloads is not sustainable.

Comment: This video may help with how you reason about performance in SwiftUI https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10160/